# R for loop ignores conditional if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, na

I'm working with a dataset in which I need R to skip over it if the value is NOT missing. I've tried making a for loop, but R ignores my logic. I've seen other for loop posts, but they do not involve the conditional being ignored.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
  my_problem <- tibble(name = c("Joe", "Joseph", "Joey"),
                       score1 = c(2, 7, 12),
                       score2 = c(NA, 5, 10))
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
solution <- tibble(name = c("Joe", "Joseph", "Joey"),
                     score1 = c(1, 7, 12),
                     score2 = c(NA, 5, 10),
                     score2edit = c(.30103, 5, 10))
```

And here's my for loop with a log10() transformation on score1 if the score2 column is NA. However, for some reason, the code ignores my if statement and jumps straight to the else.

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(my_problem)) {
    if(is.na(my_problem$score2[i])) {
      my_problem$score2edit <- log10(my_problem$score1)
    } else {
      my_problem$score2edit <- my_problem$score2
    }
  }
```

Thank you! If you could also explain why this loop isn't working, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You can use `ifelse` instead of a loop

Comment: And your condition is not working because ou are not specifying the index here `my_problem$score2edit <- log10(my_problem$score1)` and `my_problem$score2edit <- my_problem$score2` here. It should be `my_problem$score2edit[i] <- log10(my_problem$score1[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use vectorized options (`ifelse/if_else/case_when`)

```
library(dplyr)
my_problem %>% 
    mutate(score2edit = case_when(is.na(score2) ~ log10(score1), TRUE ~ score2))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  name   score1 score2 score2edit
#  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 Joe         2     NA      0.301
#2 Joseph      7      5      5    
#3 Joey       12     10     10
```

---

The `for` loop is looping through each row, so if we use that and then do the assignment/replacement for the entire dataset, the whole column gets replaced in each row